# How to get the attribute value of an element using javascript onclick()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to access the id of button , when i write the PHP variable the javascript code create error "Undefined" value.

```
function update_profile(){ $(function() {
var element = $(this);
var update_id = element.attr("id");
  var infoo = 'updated_id=' + update_id;

    document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML=infoo;


});
}
```

button code:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" onclick="update_profile()"  class="btn-xs btn-warning " id='<?php echo $user_rec[1]; ?>' >Update</button>
```

Comment: First of all I don't think you need `$(function() {` and closing it `});`

Comment: Remove `$(function() { })` and change `document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML=infoo;` to `$(".test").first().html(infoo);` or better: `$(function() { $(".btn-warning").on("click",function() { $(".test").first().html(this.id); }); });`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$(function() { });` inside of your function. You have to pass `this` to your function so it knows which element was clicked.

```js
function update_profile(element){
  var update_id = element.id;
  var infoo = 'updated_id=' + update_id;
  document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML = infoo;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test class element</div>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" onclick="update_profile(this)"  class="btn-xs btn-warning " id='idName' >Update</button>
```